# Getting the wrong result back from the stored procedure after calling another stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, resultset

We've got a stored procedure we call to create a user. Within that stored procedure we call other stored procedures to create things the user needs to start off with. Each of the stored procedures end with something like this:

```
select 1 AS statusMsg, 'User Successfuly Created' as msg;
```

The problem is that we're getting the wrong `statusMsg` and `msg` back.

We end the procedure with:

```
call createDefaultSites(l_customerguid);
select 1 AS statusMsg, 'User Successfuly Created' as msg;
```

But we're getting back the `statusMsg` and `msg` from the `createDefaultSites()` call instead of the final select.

How can we ensure that only the last statement returns a result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wound up adding an identifier to each return value and looping through them to find the one I was looking for.

```
select 1                          AS statusMsg, 
       'User Successfuly Created' AS       msg, 
       'UserCreation'             AS   msgType;
```

I honestly didn't realize I was getting back multiple result sets. If the statusMsg would've been from the first result set I *maybe* would've figured it out a little quicker.